# Cosa significa "giocare a testa e pila"?

Tags: idioms, word-meaning

Nel romanzo ***Il sentiero dei nidi di ragno*** di Italo Calvino ho letto

> "Pin alle volte vorrebbe mettersi con i ragazzi della sua età, chiedere
>   che lo lascino giocare a testa e pila, e che gli spieghino la via per
>   un sotterraneo che arriva fino in piazza mercato, ma i ragazzi lo
>   lasciano a parte, e a un certo punto si mettono a picchiarlo;"

Non capisco cosa significa "giocare a testa e pila": in che cosa consiste questo gioco?

Comment: Riunisco qui alcune fonti che mi sembrano significative: [1) origine di "a croce o pila"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/testa.shtml); [2) gioco piemontese "a testa o pila"](http://www.chambradoc.it/Dzuva-e-damouroet-di-notri-parein-35Concours-Cerlogne.1.page); [3) curva di frequenza dei punti ottenuti giocando "a testa e pila"](http://books.google.it/books?id=c79oEqVVihEC&q=%22testa+e+pila%22&dq=%22testa+e‌​+pila%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=0vztU5neJcX5oAT2uYGIBQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg); [4) gioco francese "a pila o testa"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_ou_face)

Comment: ["Croce e pila", in un Dizionario del 1749](http://books.google.it/books?id=V5UlTIQqQ58C&pg=PA389&lpg=PA389&dq=%22testa%22+%22croce%22+%22pila%22&source=bl&ots=ARk8v2cl2K&sig=Je7Kpb6656frSnBr6Cd60hzVdTE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ooXuU_KOLZTs8AWK5oHQCA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22testa%22%20%22croce%22%20%22pila%22&f=false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il brano citato in una risposta lo si può leggere integralmente, anche nell'originale dialetto piemontese, qui:http://www.chambradoc.it/Dzuva-e-damouroet-di-notri-parein-35Concours-Cerlogne.1.page

> GIOCO CON I SOLDI
>
> I nostri genitori non erano contenti. Tiravano una
>   riga o giocavano vicino ad un muro. Quasi sempre tiravano una riga.
>   Lanciavamo i soldi e cercavamo di andare vicino alla riga. Se i soldi
>   andavano oltre la riga si era già eliminati. Quello che aveva lanciato
>   il soldo più vicino alla riga iniziava il gioco e raccoglieva i soldi
>   degli altri. Il secondo poteva dire “testa” o “pila”. Il primo
>   giocatore lanciava in aria i soldi. Se il secondo giocatore aveva
>   detto testa, raccoglieva i soldi di quelli che avevano fatto pila.
>   Toccava al terzo giocatore dire testa o pila. Il primo giocatore
>   tirava nuovamente i soldi in aria e il gioco continuava così. Alla
>   fine se tutti avevano detto “testa” o “pila” e rimanevano dei soldi,
>   venivano raccolti dal primo giocatore.

Quindi questa non è semplicemente una variante vernacolare di "testa o croce" in cui si sostituisce 'croce' con 'pila', perché come noto:

> Testa o croce
>
> è una comune tecnica utilizzata per selezionare una scelta tra due
>   possibili, con uguale probabilità, utilizzando una moneta. Essa
>   consiste semplicemente nell'associare a priori le due scelte possibili
>   alle due facce della moneta, quindi nel lanciare quest'ultima in aria,
>   e considerare estratta la scelta relativa alla faccia mostrata dalla
>   moneta dopo la caduta....
>
> Talora, ci si riferisce anche al **gioco del testa o croce,** che
>   consiste semplicemente nello scommettere su di una delle due facce, e
>   quindi nell'effettuare l'estrazione.

Il gioco piemontese è piuttosto diverso, molto più complesso, ha in comune solo l'uso di monete.

Answer (score 5):

Probabilmente, questo gioco è più conosciuto come "[testa o croce](http://books.google.se/books?id=V5RbAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT225&ots=-HONMnozY5&dq=giocare%20a%20testa%20e%20pila&pg=PT225#v=onepage&q=testa%20o%20croce&f=false)".

Anticamente, era incisa una “croce” su di una faccia della moneta, mentre sull'altro lato c'era spesso la testa del sovrano. Con la stessa parola croce si definiva anche la parte mobile del conio, in contrapposizione alla “pila” che era invece la parte fissa sull'incudine, con la quale si otteneva la figura sul rovescio.

Il primo giocatore lanciava in aria i soldi. Il secondo poteva dire “testa” o “pila”. Se il secondo giocatore aveva indovinato testa, raccoglieva i soldi di quelli che avevano detto pila. Toccava al terzo giocatore dire testa o pila. Il primo giocatore tirava nuovamente i soldi in aria e il gioco continuava così. Alla fine se tutti avevano detto “testa” o “pila” e rimanevano dei soldi, venivano raccolti dal primo giocatore.

Comment: Secondo me, la "faccia" dovrebbe essere la "testa" e non la "croce".

Comment: @Charo, si parla delle due facce della moneta: una croce/nave/coda su di una faccia e la testa dell'imperatore sull'altra.

Comment: Capisco: la faccia della moneta, non la faccia del del sovrano.

Comment: Charo, per accettare la risposta puoi cliccare sul segno di spunta (checkmark) :-)

Comment: @I.M.: Può darsi che tu abbia ragione: in questo [dizionario](http://www.piemunteis.it/dep/dizionario.dep) ho trovato che in piemontese "giöghe a pila e crus" significa "giocare a testa e croce". Comunque, "pila" dovrebbe essere la "testa", quindi l'espressione "giocare a testa e pila" mi sembra un po' strana.

Comment: @Charo: In quel libro che ho menzionato sopra, ci sono tanti nomi per lo stesso gioco: cros e pila (Piemonte), cros e lettera (Milano), capo e croce (Napoli), ecc. "Testa" non necessariamente significa "pila". Diciamo che "pila" è la figura sul [rovescio](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rovescio_%28moneta%29). Se, per esempio, c'è la testa di Galileo sul dritto della [moneta](http://www.lemonete.com/index/catalogo/Repubblica_Italiana_Commemorativa/Argento/500_Lire_Galileo_Galilei_1982_Argento.htm) e l'emblema sul rovescio, si potrebbe giocare anche a "testa e pila".

Comment: @I.M.: Capisco. Comunque, il rovescio della moneta non è proprio la "croce"? Allora perché si gioca a "cros e pila" nel Piemonte?

Answer (score 5):

Azzardo un'ipotesi:
Calvino, cresciuto a Sanremo, può aver italianizzato il nome francese del gioco, che è "pile ou face", vedi [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_ou_face).
È un'ipotesi perché la frase "giocare a testa e pila" proviene da un libro e non è usata comunemente nella lingua italiana, ciononostante provo ad aggiungere alcune considerazioni:

***Il sentiero dei nidi di ragno*** è ambientato nell'estremo Ponente ligure, area geografica molto vicina alla Francia, dove le influenze reciproche tra lingua italiana e francese sono piuttosto comuni (solo a titolo di esempio la salsa di basilico, olio e pinoli si chiama "pesto" in Italia e "pistou" in Francia).

L'assonanza "pila", "pile" mi sembra evidente.

L'educazione dell'autore, nato a Cuba ma cresciuto e educato a Sanremo (Ponente ligure), per cui ha sicuramente ascoltato (o usato lui stesso) parole e modi di dire locali.

Comment: Benvenuto su [italian.se]! Qui a StackExchange ci aspettiamo risposte ragionevolmente lunghe, composte principalmente da fatti, e supportate da delle fonti; considera l'idea di allungare la tua risposta. Dovresti leggere la sezione "[How do I write a good answer?](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)", nell'[help].

Comment: Le risposte brevi e composte principalmente da opinioni sono comunque ben accette, ma è più indicato scriverle nei commenti alla domanda.

Comment: @Giulio, a me la risposta di Massimo sembra concisa ma OK: suggerisce che l'origine dell'espressione "testa o pila" usata da Calvino sia da cercarsi nell'italianizzazione del corrispondente francese "pile ou face". Calvino potrebbe aver conosciuto l'espressione a Sanremo, dove era cresciuto, dove si trova uno dei più famosi Casinò italiani e dove si parla il monegasco, affine al francese. A me sembra un suggerimento utile.

Comment: @randomatlabuser, quella che hai fornito tu si qualifica come risposta; questa, per la sua brevità e per il suo carattere di "ipotesi azzardata", si qualifica più come commento. Condivido, però, che non sussistano le condizioni per un downvote; se integri la tua risposta con un edit, sarò felice di cambiare il mio downvote in un upvote.

Comment: Ringrazio tutti per le critiche. Ho modificato, spero in meglio, la mia risposta. La mia risposta resta una "ipotesi azzardata" perché, trattandosi di un'opera letteraria, non possiamo sapere esattamente cosa pensasse Calvino e perché, non essendo io un critico letterario, non ho gli strumenti per argomentare meglio la mia risposta.